# How to add an existing custom field to a new content type

Tags: entities

In my new module I am writing, I am creating a new content type.  In this new content type, I want to attach custom fields for a media player: the media player from MediaFront and a File field with a Media File Selector widget type.

As I understand it, these fields are already defined; I just need to create an instance of each field.  How do I create an instance of each field, and then configure the extra parameters?

I haven't come across any good tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked before, for a brief example see Clive's answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20561/attach-fields-to-entity-during-install). The easiest thing to do is:

1. create your field and attach it to an entity with the UI logged in at: Admin -> Structure -> Content Types -> Manage Fields
2. use the code snippet in the below link, supplying your own `$entity_type`, `$field_name` and `$bundle_name` to get the `field_create_instance()` code outputted directly for you to copy/paste into your modules' [`hook_install()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7).
3. ...if you get good enough to know the Drupal Field API to build these `$settings` and `$config` arrays for fields without this code snippet -- more power to you .... I still use this code snippet myself, it saves time.